# How to check for internet connection before showing an option to view an incentivized app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

For my current sprite kit game that is coded in OBJECTIVE - C, I want to check for internet connection before providing the user with an option to view an incentivized ad. How would I do this? I only want the option to appear if the user is connected to the internet.

Comment: plz refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1)** Download the Reachability project from [GitHub Project from here.](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

**Step-2)** Add *Reachability.h* and *Reachability.m* files in your project from github project.

**Step-3)** In your viewController.m -> `#import "Reachability.h"`
add below code in your viewController.m

```
#define KWebURL  @"http://yourWebservicesbaseURl_or_hostName"

-(BOOL)isConnected{
     Reachability *aReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:your_Server_MainURL];

    NetworkStatus netStatus = [aReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(netStatus==0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if(netStatus==1)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if(netStatus==2)
    {
    return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

**Step-4)** **Uses:** now check conectivity using below code in your ViewDidload or where you have to impliment.

```
if ([self isConnected]) {
    // your internet is connected.
}else{
    // your internet is not connected.
}
```

**-- OR --**

if you have to make one global Object Class to use it globally from anywhere then floow from Step-3) like....

**Step-3.0)** First make New NSObject Class *i.e* *Webservice.h* and *Webservice.m*

**Step-3.1)** In your **Webservice.h** -->

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface Webservice : NSObject

+(BOOL)isConnected;

@end
```

**Step-3.2)** In your **Webservice.m** -->

```
#import "Webservice.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@implementation Webservice
+(BOOL)isConnected
{
    Reachability *aReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:your_Server_MainURL];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [aReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(netStatus==0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if(netStatus==1)
    {
    return YES;
    } 
    else if(netStatus==2)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

**Step-4)** **Uses:** now check conectivity using below code in your any viewControllers or anywhere you have to impliment.

```
if ([Webservice isConnected]) {
    // your internet is connected.
}else{
    // your internet is not connected.
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this example is wrong, the `reachabilityWithHostName` doesn't tell you if you have a connection, you have to set up some code blocks that get called as the connection status changes. There is an example in that GitHub project.